# use a cell value as text in vba formula

Tags: excel, vba

I have a variable in cell B1 that will update a file name in a formula - here is what I have:

```
\\GROUPS\GROUPS\R\Reports Dashboard\DC Daily Processing\[2018632_DC Daily Processing.xls]Virginia'!A1
```

The variable is 2018632 - this will change daily and the daily value will be in cell B1.

I have this code but cannot return the value - it brings up the open file box as if the file name is incorrect

```
Sheet1.Cells(1, 1) = "= '\\GROUPS\GROUPS\R\Reports Dashboard\DC Daily Processing\[" & Cells(2, 1) & "_DC Daily Processing.xls]Virginia'!RC"
```

I need help with the proper syntax to pull in B2 as text into the formula

I would also like to loop this so that all cells in sheet Virginia populate on my Sheet1

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).value = "= '\\GROUPS\GROUPS\R\Reports Dashboard\D2 Daily Processing\[" & Cells(2, 1).value & "_D2C Daily Processing.xls]Virginia'!RC"
```

Comment: the problem is probably also in part that @rdp is specifying column A but asking for the values to be updated in column B

Comment: I did realize that and updated the Cells(1, 2) - however I am still getting the open file pop up.  - the formula shows in cell A1 - but does not have the variable in it.

Comment: I added .value to the Cells(1, 2) and still getting pop up as if the file name is incorrect.

Comment: @rdp instead of `!RC` at the end, have you tried `!B2`